# Regex paths with Django. a list of items via clean URLs

Tags: python, django, regex

I need url like `/catalog/catalog_slug/tag_slug1/tag_slug2/tag_slug3`

```py
re_path(r'^catalog/(?P<catalog_slug>\w+)/(?P<tag_slugs>(?:\w+/)+)', ...)
```

I read how to do multiple tag_slugs, but when I mix it with a single slug by another model (catalog) [This stackoverflow answer[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360179/django-urls-how-to-pass-a-list-of-items-via-clean-urls), I got:

```py
TypeError: get() got multiple values for argument 'catalog_slug'
```

**My view**

```py
class CategorySeoTagsView(APIView):
    def get(self, catalog_slug, tag_slugs):
        pass
```

Comment: @thebjorn, The same error

Comment: @thebjorn I updated the traceback. I have no more info, just i need something like /catalog/somecatalogslug/tagslug1/tagslug2/tagslug3/ for filtering by tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to write a catch-all regex, and then post-process it in your view:

```
from django import http

def print_tags(request, catalog_slug, tag_slugs):
    print(catalog_slug)
    print(tag_slugs)
    print(tag_slugs.split('/'))
    return http.HttpResponse("OK")


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^catalog/(?P<catalog_slug>\w+)/(?P<tag_slugs>[/\w]+)/$', print_tags),
    ...
]
```

The url `http://localhost:8000/catalog/foo/bar/baz/` will then print:

```
foo
bar/baz
['bar', 'baz']
```

but you can also use get parameters:

```
def print_tags2(request, catalog_slug):
    print(catalog_slug)
    print(request.GET.getlist('tag_slugs'))
    return http.HttpResponse("OK")

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^catalog/(?P<catalog_slug>\w+)/$', print_tags2),
    ...
]
```

then you need to pass the parameters in the URL like:

```
http://nho:8752/catalog/foo/?tag_slugs=bar&tag_slugs=baz
```